# django-localeurl and static links

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, locale

I have a website in which I have set django-localeurl, and every dynamically created link works as expected but all static links dont, for example if I have an href="{ cat.get_absolute_url }" and I access the spanish (/es/) or english (/en/) site it gets redirected as expected but with href="/museum/" it gets redirected to the default language code.

Question is How do I redirect the static links to the english or spanish site depending on what the user is watching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_absolute_url (and other places you have hardcoded links) should use the @permalink decorator, or otherwise use django's "reverse" utility (which is monkey-patched in localeurl)

Comment: All the models methods get_absolute_url use @permalink decorator, the problem is when in the template I have the link harcoded like /warranty/ and when I click on it the django-localeurl middleware would take me to the default language instead of the one Im using. The harcoded links are mostly for flatpages so either Im not understanding your solution or your not understanding my problem... Still thanks so much for your response, and if im not understanding your solution please clarify.

Comment: 1] do what you can to _never_ hardcode urls into your templates.  use {% url "warranty_page" %} or whatever.

I had a conversation with carljm (current localeurl maintainer) about this exact issue, and basically he says that he will, on principle of localeurl, never support this use-case. To localeurl, it means that urls are _inherently_ stateless.  To ME, if your urls ONLY start with /[locale]/path/to/place/  then /path/to/place/ can statefully redirect.  I have a big hack to get around it if you want it, let me know.

Comment: Im using the url tag now, and its working great with it... but now the problem is with multilingual.flatpages app... I dont know how to get the url of the multilingual.flatpages using the url tag. Thats what Im missing now... Thanks

Comment: http://packages.python.org/django-localeurl/usage.html#examples  You can use that, and instead of passing it a string, pass request.LANGUAGE_CODE or similar

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I manage to get it working like this href="/{{DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE}}/quality/" where quality is a hardcoded link and it works like a charm.